# How to get the Laravel-apidoc group tree?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, api-doc

I'm happily using the mpociot/Laravel-apidoc-generator, and it works fine, except I don't get the group tree.

I followed the Laravel-apidoc-generator documentation, and I can do a nice apidoc.
But the left tree does not appear.

I added the @group annotation within each of my class.
Examples :

```
/**
 * @group Langue
 *
 * API gérant les langues
 */
class LangController
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Supprimer une langue.
 *
 * @queryParam id required Identifiant de la langue. Example: 1
 *
 * @response null
 */
public function delete(LangModel $langue) {
```

I tried to add the @group annotation to the methods, but it does not change anything :

```
/**
 * @group Langue
 * Supprimer une langue.
 *
 * @queryParam id required Identifiant de la langue. Example: 1
 *
 * @response null
 */
public function delete(LangModel $langue) {
```

After generating the apidoc with

```
php artisan apidoc:generate
```

I expect to have a nice apidoc, with a group tree.
Problem is the tree does not appear, I only get the logo and the search field.
Also, the search field does not work : when doing a research, nothing happens, the apidoc does not search anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution.

Some files has been deleted :

- apidoc/js/all.js
- apidoc/images/logo.png

After restoring them, it works.